# RAM/Latch Type IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, ram, latch

I was looking to find an IC (particularly in the 7400 series) that could act as a very simple RAM device, like a flip-flop or something. I came across 74hc373, but I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. It seems that the values on all the inputs are held only when latch enable goes from high to low. What I need is something like this, but without the latch enable or clock input requirement, since I would be accessing each bit individually. So, like one input for data and then another for resetting the held data.
Does anyone know an IC that could do this?
Thanks

P.S. if possible I would like and IC that has eight latches/ram bits (or whatever they would be called), just for the convenience of one byte.

Comment: Perhaps you need a SHIFT REGISTER?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits

Comment: *one input for data and then another for resetting the held data* SR flipflop? If you explicitly don't want a clock you need to think carefully about what accessing a bit means.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store 8 bits, the 74HC259 may be what you're after.  You'd have to add a 74HC138 if you want an addressable readout, but the 74HC259 is a readily-available part which has eight independently-writable bits.

Answer (score 0):

The 7489 springs to mind: -

[image]

There may be lower power versions but you did specifically say 7400 series.

Comment: Although there are around 10 chips in the 7400 series listed as RAM or random access memory, none of the them appear to be in stock at either Digi-Key or Mouser